# How to get Database Data in drop down in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I am trying to fetch a field's records in my dropdown. 
This is what i am doing :

The Controller:

```
$this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_new();
$rules = $this->user_m->rules_admin;
$rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required';
$this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {

    $data = $this->user_m->array_from_post(array('sip_id','sip_pass','name','key','email', 'password','phone','status','created','balance'));

    $data['key'] = $this->user_m->get_dropdown_list();

    $data['password'] = $this->user_m->hash($data['password']);


    $key=$this->user_m->save($data, $id);
    redirect('admin/user');

    }

$this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/add';
$this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
```

The Model

```
public function get_dropdown_list()
    {
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->order_by('key');
        $result = $this->db->get();
        $return = array();

        if($result->num_rows() > 0) 
            {
                foreach($result->result_array() as $row) 
                {
                $return[$row['id']] = $row['key'];
                }
            }

            return $return;

    }
```

The View :

```
<tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <td><?php echo form_dropdown('key', $key, set_value('key', $key));?></td>
</tr>
```

Can You please tell me where i am going wrong? I am getting this error :

> Undefined variable: key
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing the `$data` array to the view? You can do that by putitng the `$data` array as second parameter: `$this->load->view('view',$data);`

**EDIT:**

`$data` and `$this->data` are both different arrays. When you add something to `$data` nothing will be added to `$this->data` only to `$data`. So use one or the other.

Comment: sorry did'nt get you can you please explain.

Comment: see i do this  : $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/add';
     $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);

Comment: Can you update your question and add that code on the same spot as where it is in your file?

Comment: I used $this->data but it still the same

Comment: i manged to solve error but still one is left Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Comment: The third parameter of form_dropdown should be a single value containing the key of the option you want to be preselected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89381/discussion-between-rajan-and-meneer-venus).

Comment: @Rajan please just read [the form helper documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)